# Unable to view memory usage in stackdriver Monitoring for windows

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

**Installed stackdriver Agents on a VM instances[windows machine], followed the below steps.**

1. Open a terminal connection to your instance using RDP or a similar tool and login to Windows.
2. Open a PowerShell terminal, then run the following PowerShell commands. You don't need administrator privileges.

   `cd $env:UserProfile;
   (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://repo.stackdriver.com/windows/StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe", ".\StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe")
   .\StackdriverMonitoring-GCM-46.exe`

I also restarted the stackdriver on windows machine manually.

The StackDriver Logging API and  StackDriver Monitoring API are also enabled. I was not able to view the memory usage for a Windows machine in StackDriver monitoring.

I tried to open defender in Windows too. Nothing seems to work. As it is a high priority, looking for answers.

Answer (score -1):

I followed this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#agent-install-windows.)  Installed agent, this filter works for me:

Open the console navigation menu (menu) and select Monitoring to open Stackdriver.
Select Resource > Metrics Explorer on Stackdriver home page.

Setting Metric options as:

Resource type: GCE VM Instance
Metric: Memory utilization

Filter: state = “used”  and Instance_id = “Your_Instance_ID”

You may have to reinstall Stackdriver agent on your instance[[2]](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#uninstall)